# Uncaught Exception with COM Components in C#

Tags: c#, com, exception, com-interop

We are trying to instantiate an OCX component but it generates an exception that is not get catched by try/catch.

When starting the application from the explorer, a window asks to choice between Debug or Close the application. When I choose Debug, Visual Studio 2012 starts and I get the following message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x779ae753 in TestFwComponent.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted.
First-chance exception at 0x770ac41f in TestFwComponent.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: COleDispatchException at memory location 0x0022e228.
First-chance exception at 0x770ac41f in TestFwComponent.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x770ac41f in TestFwComponent.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EECOMException at memory location 0x0022e5b0.
First-chance exception at 0x770ac41f in TestFwComponent.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x770ac41f in TestFwComponent.exe: 0xE0434352: 0xe0434352.
First-chance exception at 0x770ac41f in TestFwComponent.exe: 0xE0434352: 0xe0434352.
```

Something strange is when I start the application directly with the debugger of VS2012, I can get the exception and continue the execution. Yes, it's dirty but this component is crap and we have to generate an exception before using it..

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException was caught
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=External component has thrown an exception.
  Source=mscorlib
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
       at FwWFLib.FwWFClass.Initialize(String ServerMachineName, String MbxName, String MbxServerProcessName, Object Controls)
       at MDT.MicroBackFill.FWClient.Core.Service.FwService.Initialize() in c:\TEMP\TestFwComponent\FwService.cs:line 49
  InnerException:
```

I want to know how can I try/catch the exception generated when starting without the debbuger ?

Comment: Trying to catch the "heap has been corrupted" exception is entirely pointless.  Your catch block is not going to be able to un-corrupt the heap.  This is a bug, it has to be fixed.  Given the usual low odds to get support for an ancient OCX control, the best approach is to delete it from all machines and backups and write off the loss.

Comment: This component can work because we don't have this issue in debug mode. I suspect the heap management is different when you have a debugger attached or not.